# SQL Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - Wrap Text when Exported to Word

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, word-wrap

I am creating a report using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and needing the exported Word document to wrap text in the table's cells as the user's will be inputting data into these table cells once exported.

I have googled and even searched SO for information, but cannot find the property values or the correct VB code to enable these features.

Please help?

Comment: So you're outputting a table into word, and need those cells to have text-wrap enabled?

Comment: Exactly. So when I export my report to Word 2010, I shouldn't have to enable Word wrap on those cells in word's table features.

Comment: Have you tried defining the column width for the table?  Not sure what happens when it's fixed at a certain width, it might wrap automatically.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845480.aspx

Comment: Where in MVS would I define the Column Width? Under the properties of a cell is has an option for Width and it is set to 2in, which in Word it will expand to the right continuously instead of wrapping.

Comment: No idea, just throwing out ideas.